# PowerShell script to retrieve local group member data

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to pull out from hundred of servers information into Excel spreadsheet about all existing local groups including their members with account status.

I have a server list - `servers.lst` for example and need to output into a CSV file the following information:

server name - domain/local group name (in format domain\name) - account name (in format domain\name) - group/user - disabled - locked out - lockout date

How do I do this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/648506/get-all-local-groups-members-and-account-status-locked-and-disabled - Here is a better phrased question from someone that I assume is either you or in your class.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of Googling is a good thing (and showing you've made a little effort is generally appreciated)!

[Here's a script that should do the data-gathering part of what you want.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Gather-Local-Group-0d0a85ad) To find that, I Googled "powershell get local group".

If you pass your server list to it, using something like the bit below, you get results close to your requirement. You should be able to modify it to suit with a little effort.

```
. Get-RemoteGroupMembership.ps1
$servers = Get-Content servers.lst
$path    = "C:\Temp\serverlst_output.csv"

Get-RemoteGroupMembership -ComputerName $servers | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
```

That's:

- Importing the function from the script I linked
- Getting the list of servers from the file (both in current directory)
- Running the function against the list, and
- Exporting it to $path as a CSV.